# Odd bug, state issue, state in child component mirroring parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could anybody please tell me what I missed here. I have an odd issue with state of child component. As soon as I handle submit and callback function sent from parent component by props invokes in child component for setting state in parent, the state in a child component itself changes oddly, namly it mirroring a state from parent component, and getting it's properties.
I have no idea how it could be, as in fact besides props which sent a callback to a child component there're no any other link between them.
Can it be that setState in a callback that set state on parent, also mutate the child state ?

```jsx
/* Parent component */
import React from "react";
import AddData from "./AddData.jsx";

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);

  const handleForm = (user) => {
    user.id = Math.random();
    const newState = [...users, user];
    setUsers(newState);
  };

  const usersList = users.map((user) => (
    <div key={user.id}>
      <p>
        Name: {user.name} ID: {user.id}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      {usersList}
      <AddData handleForm={handleForm} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```jsx
/* Child component */
import React from "react";

class AddData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: null,
  };

  handleName = (e) => {
    const { target } = e;
    this.setState({
      name: target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.handleForm(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("AddData STATE->", this.state); //{name: 'Tom', id: 0.791334565427714}

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.handleName} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddData;
```

In that console.log in child component that log a child component state, after submiting a form, I get two properties, while it seems it should be only one there. An id property is in fact property from the parent state.

Comment: Why mix class and function component styles?

Comment: Not for a special purposes, just for training.

Answer (score 1):

The `state` object reference you pass to the `handleForm` function is the same object as `user` in the function body. Updating properties applies across all references.

If you want to break the reference and only keep the new data in the parent component, I would suggest using this

```js
const handleForm = (user) => {
  setUsers((prev) => prev.concat({ ...user, id: Math.random() }));
};
```

See [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)...

> Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects

See also [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for why you should use the callback version of `setUsers()`

---

You could also break the reference at the caller side

```js
this.props.handleForm({ ...this.state });
```

Comment: Wow, Phil ! Thank you very much for your help !  Haven't reach a code editor yet, but the only this phrase ``` The state object reference you pass to the handleForm function is the same object as user in the function body. Updating properties applies across all references ``` forced me refresh a conjunction of such notions as 'Object' and 'Reference' in my memory and my mistake got clear at once.  Perfectly fine!